# Inversion of input parameters in ASM

Tags: nasm, assembly

the code is:

```
.global asm0
asm0:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    mov eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
    mov ebx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
    mov eax,ebx
    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
```

The entry is: asm0(0x2a,0x4f)

The output is: 0x4f2a

Why is the input parameters reversed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Calling Conventions**:

You may be referring to calling conventions and order of parameters being pushed. If so, **[here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100614/why-is-order-of-function-arguments-reversed#answers)** addressing as such. You can read more about calling conventions in general **[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)**.

**Endianness**:

You may also be interested in reading about endianness from the NASM documentation:

> **3.4.3 Character Constants**
>
> A character constant consists of a string up to eight bytes long, used
>   in an expression context. It is treated as if it was an integer.
>
> A character constant with more than one byte will be arranged with
>   little-endian order in mind: if you code
>
> ```
> mov eax,'abcd'
> ```
>
> then the constant generated is not 0x61626364, but 0x64636261, so that if you were then to store the value into memory,
>   it would read abcd rather than dcba. This is also the sense of
>   character constants understood by the Pentium's CPUID instruction.

**Source:** https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html

More research on your behalf to better understand this can be done by reading about the topic of **[endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)**. It's confusing when you first run into it, but there are many charts like this one to help demonstrate it:

[image]

**Image source**: https://agilescientific.com/blog/2017/3/31/little-endian-is-legal

Finally, there's an excellent video from OpenSecurityTraining that does a great job of explaining endianness and order of parameters/arguments with calling conventions. [Click here to view it](https://youtu.be/H4Z0S9ZbC0g?t=1015).